# How connect websocket client to the server?

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, socket.io, boost-asio

I have server URL like this `ws://host:port?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmMTA2MWFmNjViYzY5MDQ4ZGJmODc1YSIsImlhdCI6MTU5NjU0NTAxNCwiZXhwIjo0NzUyMzA1MDE0fQ.E-WuI5jSow69WZPZtQbVKkNR8TIO1DmYwYLgaqREkfE` and want to connect my websocket clinet with that server.

Here is code example.

````
    std::string host_="host";
    std::string port_="port";
    // tcp::resolver resolver_;
    auto const results = resolver_.resolve(host_, port_);
    
//    websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
    ws_.handshake(host_, "/");

    ws_.write(net::buffer(std::string(send_data_.dump())));

    // Debug
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    ws_.read(buffer);
    std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Data sended!\n";
    send_data_.clear(); ```
````

Comment: what is `ws_`, what is `resolver_`, what is `send_data_`? Please provide a [mre] and explain what the problem is with this code?

Comment: @AlanBirtles those variables are literally described in the comments in the code snippet. I agree there's no way to know what is wrong according to the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
//    websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
    ws_.handshake(host_, "/");
```

You resolved an IP endpoint but never connect the underlying socket:

```
std::string host_="host";
std::string port_="port";
net::io_context io(1);
tcp::resolver resolver_(io);
auto const results = resolver_.resolve(host_, port_);

websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_(io);

connect(ws_.next_layer(), results);

ws_.handshake(host_, "?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmMTA2MWFmNjViYzY5MDQ4ZGJmODc1YSIsImlhdCI6MTU5NjU0NTAxNCwiZXhwIjo0NzUyMzA1MDE0fQ.E-WuI5jSow69WZPZtQbVKkNR8TIO1DmYwYLgaqREkfE");

ws_.write(net::buffer(std::string(send_data_.dump())));
```

Note the `connect` line. Of course you